# How to pass more than one parameters to the Zend_Db_Select?

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, zend-db

I am a ZF beginner and I can not find  answer by googling.
I have something like that:

```
$query->where('sc.year BETWEEN ? AND ?', array($startYear, $endYear));
```

As you can see I try to pass 2 parameters as array (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3305202/2995868). But it does not work. I have performed a simple test:

```
$query->where("sc.year BETWEEN ? AND ?",array(1,2))
->where("sc.week BETWEEN IF(year = ?, ?, 1) AND IF(year = ?, ?,53)",array(3,4,5,6));
```

What I expect to see in raw SQL:

```
...WHERE (sc.year BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AND (sc.week BETWEEN IF(year = 3, 4, 1) AND IF(year = 5, 6, 53))
```

What I really see:

```
...WHERE (sc.year BETWEEN 1, 2 AND 1, 2) AND (sc.week BETWEEN IF(year = 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1) AND IF(year = 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 53))
```

So ZF just converts array to string and inserts it like single parameter.

Also I try something in native PHP style:

```
$query->where('sc.year BETWEEN ? AND ?', $startYear, $endYear);
```

It still not works.

I know, that I can use string functions like sprintf, but I want to understand how to pass more than one parameter via Zend_Db in right way.

Comment: You can try `$query->where("sc.year BETWEEN $startYear AND $endYear");`

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan thanks! It is really beautiful solution! But I think, parameters passed that way will not be properly quoted into statement. Anyway it will work for me,because I use  simple integer parameters.

Comment: Your first code sample is the correct way. Could you give more info about why this doesn't work? If you `echo $query` to output the SQL, what to you get?

Comment: @TimFountain I have edited question, please see above.

Comment: Based on the output you're getting, it seems like `$startYear` and `$endYear` are already arrays. Are you sure they're just integers?

Comment: @TimFountain $startYear and $endYear are integer variables.